# Trying to shorten length of a field using field calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, vbscript

I currently have a field that has text for a hyperlink to a photo that I am trying to shorten. I only need the name of the file at the end but the length of the name varies by a few characters. The path before the name is always 59 characters. I have been trying to use "Right( [Overall_Ph], Len( [Overall_Ph]), -59 )" in the field calculator to remove the first 59 characters but it is returning an error.

Comment: Looks like you simply have an extraneous comma just before -59, in other words you want len minus 59 char

Answer (score 5):

Switch your Field Calculator parser to "Python" and try this:

```py
!Overall_Ph![59:]
```

This will output the rest of the field value, starting *after* the 59th character (Python indexes start at `0`)

Alternatively, if you wish to stick with VBScript Parser (I would recommend starting to use the Python parser) use the `mid()` function instead of `right()`

```vbs
mid([Overall_ph], 60)
```

Which will function in the same way as the Python one - output the value starting at the 60th character.

Comment: @TimWoodfield If this has worked for you, the way to say "thanks" here is to upvote and accept the answer.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)